# запись в куки php

Tags: php, opencart, php7

При просмотре товара записываю его значение в куки:

`setcookie("UserProductsView[]", (int)$this->request->get['product_id'], time()+3600);`

но почему-то записывается максимум 2 товара, и когда делаю: `print_r($_COOKIE['UserProductsView']);`

то выдает вот это:

```
Array ( [product] => 50 [0] => 50 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что запись `setcookie("UserProductsView[]")` валидна, так как в документации такого варианта нет, есть только с явным указанием ключа.

Попробуйте формировать массив на уровне кода + сериализовать. Примерный код:

```
$usersProducts = unserialize(($_COOKIE['UserProductsView'] ?? NULL));
if(!is_array($usersProducts))$usersProducts = [];
$usersProducts[] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
setcookie("UserProductsView", serialize($usersProducts), time()+3600,"/");
```